# search bar query with like operator

Tags: php, mysql

what will be the search query for a search bar with dropdown field.
i have to fetch the results from db which has 2 tables
1. content_ref_table   with fields
   title,description,url,course_id

2. course_ref_table with fields
   course_id,courses

i have to search for the entered text in title and description field corresponding to selected course

HTML

```
<input id ="search_bar" name= "search_bar"type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" >
            <span class="input-group-addon">

               <select class="form-control" name="selectVal">
                    <option value="course">Select Course</option>
                    <?php
                        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"call courses_dropdown()");
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                        {   

                            echo "<option value='" . $row['courses'] ."'>" . $row['courses'] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?> 
                </select>
            </span>  
<span class="input-group-addon">

                    <button type="submit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                    </button>  


                </span>
                </form>
```

php

```
<?php
 include 'includes/dbconfig.php';
 $search_term = $_GET['search_bar'];
  $select_course = $_GET['select_course'];
  $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM content_ref_table WHERE            title LIKE  '%".$search_term."%' OR description LIKE  '%".$search_term."%'  LIMIT 0 , 30")
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). You are also mixing `and` and `or` clauses without `()` to enforce the execution order, so you're probably going to get wonky results.

Comment: suggest me some better way out

Comment: oh. and `$search_term` and `$searchTerm`? You really need to a good long hard look at that code...

Comment: Sorry what is 'courses_dropdown()' ? Stored procedure?

Comment: it is fetching the course list from course_ref_table i.e select courses from course_ref_table

Comment: what is the out put of courses_dropdown(). will it return both course_id and course values?

Comment: Try my query and let me know if it works.

Comment: course_dropdown() will return the name of courses @RavinderReddy

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this in my opinion:

```
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM content_ref_table,course_ref_table 
        WHERE title LIKE '%".$search_term."%' OR description LIKE '%".$search_term."%' 
        and content_ref_table.course_id = course_ref_table.course_id 
        and courses = '".$selected_course."' LIMIT 0 , 30")
```